# Why are the addresses of malloced 2D array not what I expect?

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, pointer-arithmetic

With the aim of allocating memory for a 2D array in C I run

```
double (*t)[2] = malloc(sizeof(*t)*4);
```

I expected this to allocate 64 bytes (4 times the size of two doubles). That is, I expected t[0] and t[1] to have room for 4 doubles each. For this reason, I thought that the address of t[0] and t[1] should be separated by 32 bytes. However, I find that they are separated by 16 bytes (corresponding to only two doubles).

```
printf("Address of t[0]: %p\n", t[0]);  // Address of t[0]: 00C92490
printf("Address of t[1]: %p\n", t[1]);  // Address of t[1]: 00C924A0
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Each `t[n]` consists of two doubles. So it's no surprise that `t[0]` and `t[1]` is  separated by 16 bytes (assuming a `double` is 8 bytes). The allocation allows you to access `t[0][0], t[0][1], t[1][0], t[1][1], t[2][0], t[2][1], t[3][0], t[3][1]`. Just like `double t[4][2]` would. If you really wanted `double t[2][4]` you need to swap `2` and `4`

Comment: What `double (*t)[2]` points at will become equivalent to a `double [2]`. However, `t[0]` etc performs pointer arithmetic on `double [2]` items. It might be easier to understand the code if you write `double (*t)[2] = malloc( sizeof(double[4][2]) );` and treat `t` as a `double [4][2]` array from there on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a misunderstanding in the declaration and the allocation here. You declare `t` to be an array, where each element in the array `t` is an array of two `double` elements. Then you allocate enough space for four elements in `t`.

Your definition and allocation is equivalent to:

```
double t[4][2];
```

If you want to create an array of two elements, where each element is a dynamically allocated array, you need an array of pointers instead:

```
double *t[2] = { malloc(sizeof(*t[0]) * 4), NULL };
```

The above define `t` as an array of two elements, each elements is a pointer to a `double`, and you initialize the first element (`t[0]`) to point to an array of four `double` elements, and the second (`t[1]`) to be a null pointer.

---

The important part is the difference between

```
double (*t)[2];`
```

and

```
double *t[2];
```

Using [the clockwise/spiral rule](https://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) the first defines `t` as "a pointer to an array of two `double`". The second defines `t` as "an array of two pointers to `double`".

Answer (score 1):

> I expected this to allocate 64 bytes (4 times the size of two doubles)

This your expectation is correct. But this your conclusion

> That is, I expected t[0] and t[1] to have room for 4 doubles each. For
> this reason,

is wrong.

This line

```
double (*t)[2] = malloc(sizeof(*t)*4);
```

is equivalent to

```
double (*t)[2] = malloc( sizeof( double[4][2] ) );
```

because The type of the expression `*t` is `double[2]`.

So `t[0]` and `t[1]` have the type array type `double[2]`. `sizeof( double[2] )` is equal to `16`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    double( *t )[2] = malloc( sizeof( double[4][2] ) );

    printf( "sizeof( double[2] ) = %zu\n", sizeof( *t ) );
    printf( "Address of t[0]: %p\n", ( void * )t[0] );
    printf( "Address of t[1]: %p\n", ( void * )t[1] );
    printf( "(char * )t[0] + sizeof( double[2] ) = %p\n",
        ( void * )( ( char * )t[0] + sizeof( double[2] ) ) );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
sizeof( double[2] ) = 16
Address of t[0]: 00B971D8
Address of t[1]: 00B971E8
(char * )t[0] + sizeof( double[2] ) = 00B971E8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double (*t)[2] = malloc( sizeof *t * 4 );
```

creates `t` as a *4x2* array of `double`, not a 2x4 array.  The result looks like:

```
   +---+        +---+
t: |   | -----> |   | t[0][0]
   +---+        + - +
                |   | t[0][1]
                +---+
                |   | t[1][0]
                + - +
                |   | t[1][1]
                +---+
                |   | t[2][0]
                + - +
                |   | t[2][1]
                +---+
                |   | t[3][0]
                + - +
                |   | t[3][1]
                +---+
```

hence why the addresses of `t[0]` and `t[1]` are 16 (2 * `sizeof (double)`) bytes apart.

If you want to dynamically allocate a *2x4* array of `double`, you need to write

```
double (*t)[4] = malloc( sizeof *t * 2 );
```

IOW,

```
T (*p)[COLUMNS] = malloc( sizeof *p * ROWS );
```

You're allocating enough space for `ROWS` instances of `T [COLUMNS]`.